# Atomic physics - photoelectric emission

Tags: atomic-physics, photoelectric-effect

I understand that when photoelectric emission occurs:
$$h\nu = h\nu_o + K.E.$$
Where $\nu_o$ represents the threshold frequency. What I don't understand is what happens if the frequency is just equal to the threshold frequency? Won't the electron have zero kinetic energy, hence zero velocity? Thus how does it escape?

Answer (score 1):

The equation for photoelectric emission $$h\nu = h\nu_o + K.E.$$
tells us that if photoelectric emission occurs we can find its frequency, $\nu$ given its initial frequency $\nu_o$ and some kinetic energy. If $\nu = \nu_o$, then there is no photoelectric emission and no kinetic energy.

Answer (score 0):

K.E. represents the "extra"-energy, in addition, to the minimum energy $h\nu_o$ to be supplied, to energize the electrons up to the level where they barely manage to escape somehow from the metal.

Comment: Yeah, it's that somehow that seems to be confusing me.

Comment: @Gummybears If the frequency of the electron is the threshold frequency, the electron can escape, but does not go anywhere. Effectively- no escaping. You never see this in "real" life, though, because of thermal fluctuations; electrons would "pop" out, with some small amount of kinetic energy.